# only keep certain words in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I was wondering if there was a way to strip away text that isn't the text I needed. I need to remove all text from a screenshot that isn't "loud noises". I've searched all over, but I haven't found an answer. My code:

```
if "loud noises" in text:
    print(text)
else:
    pass
```

I need a way to only display the text "loud noises", and nothing else. (it's a long story)

Comment: `if "loud noises" in text: print("loud noises")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is:

```
def getWord(idx,word,get):
    try:
        total = 0
        for i in range(len(get)):
            if word[idx + i] == get[i]:
                total += 1
        if total == len(get):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except IndexError:
        # out of range
        return
text = "I make loud noises"
newtext = ""
for idx in range(len(text)):
    if getWord(idx,text,"loud noises"):
        newtext += "loud noises"

print(newtext)
```

It accomplishes what you're thinking of, and could be used as mehtod.